# Mostrar o valor total apenas se estiver como PAGO

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema de seleção que envia PAGO para o banco de dados como ID: 1 e NÃO PAGO como ID: 0, e fiz uma verificação ao invés de aparecer o valor 1 ou 0 aparecer PAGO ou NÃO PAGO. Até ai tudo bem, mais eu um sistema na mesma tabela que se chama "Valor Total", onde ele pega todos os valores dos anúncios do banco de dados e mostra na tela, e eu queria que ele mostrasse o valor do anúncio apenas se estiver como NÃO PAGO, os que estão PAGO ele não mostrar no Valor Total. Fiz um if mais mesmo assim não deu certo e esta bugando, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
                <th style="text-align:center;">Valor Total: R$ <?php
                if($anuncio['estado'] == 1){
                $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(valor) AS total FROM 
                anuncios WHERE id_usuario = :id_usuario");
                $sql->bindValue(":id_usuario", $_SESSION['cLogin']);
                $sql->execute();

                $ln = $sql->fetchObject();

                echo number_format($ln->total);
                }
                ?></th>
```

Comment: Não seria `WHERE id_usuario = :id_usuario AND estado = 1`?

Comment: Então, não quer ir.

Comment: Ae foi, obrigado <3